# How can I lessen the verbosity of my populate method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I wrote a form object to populate an Order, Billing, and Shipping Address objects. The `populate` method looks pretty verbose. Since the form fields don't correspond to Address attributes directly, I'm forced to manually assign them. For example:

```
shipping_address.name = params[:shipping_name]
billing_address.name  = params[:billing_name]
```

Here's the object. Note that I snipped most address fields and validations, and some other code, for brevity. But this should give you an idea. Take note of the populate method:

```
class OrderForm
  attr_accessor :params

  delegate :email, :bill_to_shipping_address, to: :order
  delegate :name, :street, to: :shipping_address, prefix: :shipping
  delegate :name, :street, to: :billing_address,  prefix: :billing

  validates :shipping_name, presence: true
  validates :billing_name,  presence: true, unless: -> { bill_to_shipping_address }

  def initialize(item, params = nil, customer = nil)
    @item, @params, @customer = item, params, customer
  end

  def submit
    populate
    # snip
  end

  def order
    @order ||= @item.build_order do |order|
      order.customer = @customer if @customer
    end
  end

  def shipping_address
    @shipping_address ||= order.build_shipping_address
  end

  def billing_address
    @billing_address ||= order.build_billing_address
  end

  def populate
    order.email = params[:email]

    shipping_address.name          = params[:shipping_name]
    shipping_address.street        = params[:shipping_street]
    # Repeat for city, state, post, code, etc...

    if order.bill_to_shipping_address?
      billing_address.name          = params[:shipping_name]
      billing_address.street        = params[:shipping_street]
      # Repeat for city, state, post, code, etc...
    else
      billing_address.name          = params[:billing_name]
      billing_address.street        = params[:billing_street]
      # Repeat for city, state, post, code, etc...
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the controller code:

```
  def new
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(@item)
  end

  def create
    @order_form = OrderForm.new(@item, params[:order], current_user)
    if @order_form.submit
      # handle payment
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Noe I am not interested in `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, which presents several problems, hence why I wrote the form object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def populate
  order.email = params[:email]
  shipping_params = %i[shipping_name shipping_street]
  billing_params = order.bill_to_shipping_address? ?
   shipping_params : %i[billing_name billing_street]

  [[shipping_address, shipping_params], [billing_address, billing_params]]
  .each{|a, p|
     a.name, a.street = params.at(*p)
  }
end
```

Comment: Nice and companct +1! Is `%i` Ruby 2.0 only?

Comment: Yes. It was introduced in Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address, class_name: 'Address'
  has_one :billing_address, class_name: 'Address'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address, :billing_address
  before_save :clone_shipping_address_into_billing_address, if: [check if billing address is blank]
```

Then when you set up the form, you can have fields_for the two Address objects, and side step the populate method entirely.

Comment: I spent hours looking into the problem and came to the conclusion nesting the forms is not worth it. It causes many problems, for the user experience.

Comment: To clarify. First problem: Errors are duplicated even if the user has checked `bill to shipping address`. Second issue, if you over come this by using `reject_if`, the billing form will disappear after a validation error since it was reject... There are several other problems too long to get into.

Answer (score 1):

A possible fix would be to use a variable for retrieving those matching params, like so:

```
def populate
    order.email = params[:email]

    shipping_address.name                    = params[:shipping_name]
    shipping_address.street                = params[:shipping_street]
    # etc...

    #set a default state
    shipping_or_billing = "shipping_"
    #or use a ternary here...
    shipping_or_billing = "billing_" if order.bill_to_shipping_address?

    billing_address.name                    = params["shipping_or_billing" + "name"]
    billing_address.street                = params["shipping_or_billing" + "street"]
    ...
end
```

Comment: Another option would be to iterate over params for specific groups (in this example, I have a form with dynamic fields 
`params[:response].each do |question_id, answer|`

Answer (score 1):

Your address classes should probably have a method that would set the values for all the address properties from a `hash` that it would receive as an argument.

That way your `populate` method would only check for `order.bill_to_shipping_address?` and them pass the correct dictionary to the method I'm suggesting.

That method on the other hand, would just assign the values from the `hash` to the correct properties, without the need for a conditional check.